# When should a text input be auto selected?

Tags: html5

By default in most browsers, text inputs become fully selected when you tab into them, but not when you click on them. But in some instances, applications choose to focus the text input when it receives focus (either by tabbing into it or by clicking on it). My inclination is to allow the browser to do it's thing and leave the default behavior, but we often get requests for this behavior too.

I am looking for guidance on when you should write code to automatically select the contents of a text input when it receives focus.

Comment: Generally, selecting the text on click is used on readonly text fields meant for copying content. Consider the share field on [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ). It's obvious that the use case is to copy the text, so selecting all of it makes sense. [It also happens that this behavior is trivial to add](http://jsfiddle.net/c2rn2smq/).

Answer (score 4):

### This is a tradeoff decision, so decide by understanding the tradeoffs

There is no "right" answer here because you are trading off:

- The benefits of UX consistency with default browser behavior.
- The potential benefits of custom UX behavior to help users navigate the form faster.
- The benefit of consistent behavior for mouse vs tab focus.
- The benefit of consistent behavior *within* your form (i.e. should tabbing into an `input`  provide consistent behavior within your form)

Additionally, it may help to understand ***why*** the mouse vs keyboard focus behaves differently:

- A mouse allows precise positioning of a cursor within the input box, so a UX decision has been made to give users more control by allowing the user to select the precise cursor location. A user with a mouse can still select the entire `input` by clicking and dragging.
- A <kbd>Tab</kbd> button doesn't have this ability so a UX decision has been made to select the entire text instead.

To make your decision, you can prioritize the following considerations depending on your app:

1. Would a custom/non-default focus behavior **help the user complete the form better**?  For example, if a user is most likely to replace (and not edit) the contents of an input box, then selection of the entire box may help the user complete the form faster.
2. Are the benefits of #1 worth the cost of non-standard form behavior?

Only you can make that decision, but by understanding the tradeoffs you can make it in a well-reasoned way.

Comment: Well said. Only by an unbiased introspective look at the reasoning and the *clear* benefits can a decision be made, and whilst we can help provide the framework for understanding this, it's bound to hinge on generalisations unless we have all the pertinent facts. As a result, only the OP can answer his own question for their own scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's really a hard choice here.

Assuming the text input looks like any other text box, the options seem to to be:

- **A)** Override the default behaviour because sometimes you get requests for it - and because you can.
- **B)** Leave the default behaviour alone because that's what users expect in almost every other scenario in which they use such a common and recognisable ui element whether in this browser, another browser or any other software.

However, maybe there's more options which are like some kind of middle ground:

- **C)** Override a very specific instance because you believe the default behaviour is wrong, and it's not a scenario in which the users will have particular expectations, and this is backed up by evidence from user testing, and it won't lead user into a situation where they try to use the learnt behaviour you have provided in other places, only to find that everyone the behaviour is different.
- **D)** Override the behaviour because this is a text input that is different to other inputs - it looks different, has extended functionality, and serves more purposes than simply entering a value. Rightly or wrongly, browser omniboxes could be argued as falling into this category although I know not everyone agrees - which just shows the problem when expectations *are* broken!

I'm thinking for the purposes of this question, the answer that applies is probably (B) **leave the default behaviour alone**?

Comment: Would it make a difference if you thought the users intent in focusing the textbox (via click or tab) carried the intent to edit? vs the intent to modify? For example, Chrome's address bar fully selects when you click it (how many people edit URLs and how many type something new?). But google's search textbox does not auto-select. People maybe refine their search more than replace it. ...or am I putting too much thought into this and should let the defaults do their thing?